# Visual Studio, ASP.NET MVC, SQL Server - database schema

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I created a SQL Server database in my ASP.NET MVC app with relations between the tables. I need a way to see the database schema for whole tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the SQL server or object explorer built in to Visual Studio isn't good enough for you (did you try those?)
You can use SQL Server Management Studio. Free download I think..?
Then use it to connect to your DB and you can get a schema as a diagram view/edit data etc..
There is also a lighter weight version of it as an app... but I don't recall its exact name atm.